# I Linked local jquery files in my next js 14 project in layout.js, some time it worked but some time it gave me errors like jquery not define

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, next.js

When I load project, I get errors like this:

```
jQuery not defined 
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: a is not a function
```

And when I refresh page multiple time some time it worked and some time start giving me same errors:

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <Providers>
        <body className={inter.className}>
          <Header />
      
          {children}
          <Footer />
          <Script src="/assets/js/jquery.min.js" />
          <Script src="/assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" />
          <Script src="/assets/js/magnific-popup.min.js" />
          <Script src="/assets/js/main.js" />
          <Script src="/assets/js/meanmenu.js" />
          <Script src="/assets/js/nice-select.min.js" />
          <Script src="/assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js"   />
        </body>

      </Providers>
    </html>
  )
}
```

[Code project folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cr3o3.png)

Comment: Please post the code as a text, not an image.